# extract multiindex types in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I `set_index()` using 3 of the columns. I would like to extract the data type associated with each index. How can I do this efficiently? I don't want to do `type(df.index.get_level_values())` since the df is large.

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,1,2], "time": [1, 1, 2, 2], "val": [1,2,3,4]})
df.set_index(keys=["id", "time"], inplace=True)
type(df.index.get_level_values(1))
#pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index
```

I would also like to know the type of the actual data that is in the index (ie looking at this i know it's integers but it would be nice to get something like this also:

```
type(df.index.get_level_values(1).values[0])
#numpy.int64
```

Comment: If you're setting the index from three columns, why not just take `.dtype` of each of the columns?

Comment: true but assume the index has already been set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `[lev.dtype.type for lev in index.levels]`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,1,2], "time": [1, 1, 2, 2], "val": [1,2,3,4]})
df.set_index(keys=["id", "time"], inplace=True)
index = df.index

print([lev.dtype.type for lev in index.levels])
# [<class 'numpy.int64'>, <class 'numpy.int64'>]

# Alternatively, there is the private attribute, `_inferred_type_levels`,  
# but this is probably not what you are looking for.
print(index._inferred_type_levels)
# ['integer', 'integer']
```

---

`index.levels` is a FrozenList of 1-dimensional Indexes:

```
In [172]: list(index.levels)
Out[172]: 
[Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64', name='time')]
```